# Trying to use .htaccess rules to redirect to load FR content w/ a FR domain and EN content w/ an EN Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki with mulitlingual subpages.

When I go to "english.com/Page_title" I want to load just that (which is the default)

When I go to "french.com/Page_title" I want to load the /fr subpage, which is "french.com/Page_title/fr"

and here's my current rules:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^:]*\.(php|src|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|inc|swf|flv|phtml|pl|ico|html|shtml|zip|rar|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php?title - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1\%26$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (//+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1%1$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ /wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
```

Taken from here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Page_title_--_PHP_as_a_CGI_module,_no_root_access#Alternate_option_V

I've plays with various RewriteCond's and rules but can't get it to work, always endless redirects or 500's.

Comment: How have you set up MediaWiki to determine what language to use from the request? Does it look at the original request path, or does it get the information from the query string?

Answer (score 1):

```
#
# Media Wiki
#
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule     ^[^:]*\.(php|src|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|inc|swf|flv|phtml|pl|ico|html|shtml|zip|rar|svg|eot|ttf|woff)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php?title - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^french\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/fr$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/fr [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\&(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1\%26$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (//+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1%1$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /wiki/index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ /wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page [L,QSA]
```

Fixed it.